# Problema al relacionar 4 tablas con left join

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlite

Tengo un problema con SQL. Quiero hacer la relación de 4 tablas (usuario, appuserFuncitonRelation, organizaciones, GroupCommerce) donde la organización está relacionada con groupCOmmerce y appuserFunctionRelation está relacionado con ambos y con el otro tiene el id de usuario. Lo que quiero hacer es traer el GroupCOmmerce que el usuario no tiene. ¿Cómo se puede hacer eso?

```
/* Create DB */
Use master;
GO
IF DB_ID (N'JoinsDB3') IS NOT NULL
DROP database JoinsDB3;

CREATE DATABASE JoinsDB3;
GO
Use JoinsDB3;
GO

/*User
ID|Description
1 |admin

Organization
ID|Description
1 |TestOrg
2 |TestOrg2

CommerceGroup
ID|Organization|Description
1 |1 |TestGC
2 |1 |TestGC2
3 |1 |TestGC3
4 |2 |TestGC4

AppUserFunctionsRelation
User|organization|CommerceGroup 
1 |1 |1*/

CREATE TABLE Organizacion(
[ID] [int] NOT NULL,
[Description] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL);

GO



INSERT INTO [Organizacion] ([ID], [Description])
VALUES (1, 'TestOrg'),(2, 'TestOrg2'); 
GO


CREATE TABLE [User](
[ID] [int] NOT NULL,
[Description] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL);

GO

INSERT INTO [User] ([ID], [Description])
VALUES (1, 'admin'); 
GO

CREATE TABLE CommerceGroup(
[ID] [int] NOT NULL,
[Organization] [int] NOT NULL,
[Description] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL);
GO

INSERT INTO [CommerceGroup] ([ID], [Organization], [Description])
VALUES (1, 1, 'TestCG'),(2, 1, 'TestCG2'),(3, 1, 'TestCG3'),(4, 1, 'TestCG4'); 
GO

CREATE TABLE AppUserFunctionsRelation(
[User] [int] NOT NULL,
[Organization] [int] NOT NULL,
[CommerceGroup]  [int] NOT NULL);
GO

INSERT INTO AppUserFunctionsRelation ([User], [Organization], [CommerceGroup])
VALUES (1, 1, 1); 
GO

/*QUERY*/
SELECT CommerceGroupID  FROM (SELECT 
   [AppUserFunctionsRelation].[user] as userID,
   [CommerceGroup].Organization,
   [CommerceGroup].ID AS CommerceGroupID ,[CommerceGroup].Description AS CommerceGroupDescription
   FROM [AppUserFunctionsRelation]
right JOIN [CommerceGroup] ON CommerceGroup.Organization = AppUserFunctionsRelation.Organization AND AppUserFunctionsRelation.[CommerceGroup] = [CommerceGroup].ID) as Temp
Where Temp.userID IS NULL
```

tengo eso pero no funciona, gracias.

Comment: pero como relaciona el usuario con las demas tablas

Comment: Hola gracias por responder
Esta la relacion con AppUserFunctionsRelation que con esa relacionas las 3 tablas

Comment: En este caso el usuario 1 tiene la organizacion 1 y el grupo de comercio 1

Answer (score 2):

Si no me equivoco se trata de hacer esto:

```
select distinct u.ID,  a1.organization, a1.CommerceGroup 
from [User] u, AppUserFunctionsRelation a1
where a1.CommerceGroup  not in (select a2.CommerceGroup  from 
AppUserFunctionsRelation a2 where a2.JobId = u.ID)
```

Basicamente esta query te obtiene todos los usuarios con todos los commerceGroup que no tienen.

Estoy convencido que se puede hacer mas eficiente pero esta es la primera solucion que normalmente se aplica. El siguiente paso, como muy bien has dicho, seria trabajar con `joins` y seguramente un `having` junto al `group by`

Comment: mmm no, me trae muchas filas esa consulta, creo que no es lo que necesito ahi arriba puse una nueva consulta con la que pude avanzar  pero me sigue trayendo lo que no espero, porque me trae todos los grupos de comercios que no tiene el usuario y yo solo necesito traer los grupos de comercio que no tiene sobre la organizacion que tiene relacionada

Answer (score 0):

Si mal no entendí, lo que necesitas es realizar el filtro contra `User` + `Organization`, por lo que esta última debiera estar contemplada en el filtro, además del usuario.

Tomando tu última consulta editada como referencia, y sólo en teoría, se me ocurre esto:

```
DECLARE @User int = 1;
SELECT
    @User,
    o.ID,
    o.[Description],
    cg.Id,
    cg.[Description]
FROM 
    CommerceGroup cg INNER JOIN Organizations o
    ON cg.Organization = o.Id
WHERE
    cg.Organization + ';' + cg.Id NOT IN
    (
        SELECT a.organization + ';' + a.commercegroup 
        FROM AppUserFunctionsRelation a
            WHERE a.[User] = @User 
    )
GO
```

Comment: Hola quinqui, lo que necesito esta en la respuesta de arriba, pero nose si se puede mejorar, gracias por tu tiempo

Comment: Te sugiero cortar esa consulta y agregarla al final de tu pregunta original, como parte de los intentos que has realizado para solucionar el problema. (Las respuestas son para quienes queremos ayudarte, sólo debieras agregar una respuesta si es la respuesta correcta a tu propio problema, vale decir, que encontraste solito la respuesta ^_^.)

Comment: Gracias quinqui, soy nuevo acá,  no se poner con el tag SQL todavía
Saludos

Comment: Ahora leí que esa fue la solución que encontraste, entonces sí está bien que esté en las respuestas ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @User int = 1;
SELECT  
    o.[Description],
    cg.ID,
    cg.[Description]
FROM 
    CommerceGroup cg
    INNER JOIN Organization o ON cg.Organization = o.ID
        AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM AppUserFunctionsRelation a 
            WHERE o.ID = a.Organization AND a.[User] = @User)
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM AppUserFunctionsRelation a 
    WHERE cg.ID = a.CommerceGroup AND cg.Organization = a.Organization AND a.[User] = @User)
GO
```

Lo pude conseguir :D
precisamente esa es la consulta  que necesito esa funciona muy bien, pero no se si se puede mejorar con join en vez not exist

Comment: Para evitar el `EXISTS` dentro del `FROM` principal, podrías reemplazarlo por otro JOIN: `... INNER JOIN AppUserFunctionsRelation a ON o.ID = a.Organization AND a.[User] = @User`, ya que sólo quieres los Commerce de la Organization del User, no?

Comment: Gracias quinqui, lo voy aprobar :D

Answer (score 0):

Si no entendí mal, esto podrías ayudarte:

```
select *
       from [User] u
       cross join CommerceGroup c
       where c.id not in (select CommerceGroup
                            from AppUserFunctionsRelation
                            where [User] = u.id)
```

Por cada `User` hacemos un producto cartesiano con los `CommerceGroup` y solo retornamos aquellos que no estuvieran en `AppUserFunctionsRelation`.